# Simple.. Finding bug on Update calculation I think

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have a rectangle with a percentage 1.0f
this means 100%
so at certain point i set this percentage to 0.0f in another function by mouse click
and now to fill the rectangle back to 100% or 1.0f is where the problem is
I see the rectangle growing back up but never in the right time (time_to_fill_in_seconds)
on update i have the following

```
    private void updateInterface(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        this.newGameTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        if ((rectangle.getPercentage() == 0) &&
            (rectangle.getAddValue() == 0))
        {
            float time = 1000 * time_to_fill_in_seconds;

            // update rectangle add values
            rectangle.incrementToIn(1.0f, time);
       }

       rectangle.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

and inside rectangle

```
    // Value to be added on each Update
    public void incrementToIn(float targetPercentage, float time)
    {
        setAddValue((targetPercentage - currentPercentage) / time);
    }


    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if ((percentage <= 1.0f) && (addValue > 0))
        {
            if (percentage == 1.0f)
                addValue = 0;
            percentage += addValue;
        }
    }
```

I already lost like 2 days searching for the problem...
The bar takes too long to fill
what am i doing wrong?

this is probably something very simple...
if you see something wrong I appreciate your help
thank you

Comment: Probably without touching the real cause but all your floating point comparisons are wrong were you test the equality. In floating point arithmetic we are not allowed to compare with concrete values (`1.0f`). Take a look at remarks section here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pheraps I am wrong but it seems that percentage won't never be 0. In fact Update sets addValue to 0 but not percentage.
Moreover I suggest you to replace the test
percentage == 1
with
percentage >= 1.

Comment: the percentage is set to 0 in another function on mouse click that I can see the rectangle growing. The only problem must be the timing or the addValue. Probably something related with gameTime not being used in the calculations. Sorry my english.